# Counting the number of records in an object store in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I want to basic count the number of records in my indexedDB database.

Currently my code looks like

**Javascript**

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["data"], "readonly");
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("data");
var cursor = objectStore.openCursor();  
    var count = objectStore.count();
    console.log(count);
```

I would love for this to say output just 3, but instead i get.

**Output**

```
        IDBRequest {onerror: null, onsuccess: null, readyState: "pending", transaction: IDBTransaction, source: IDBObjectStore…}
    error: null
    onerror: null
    onsuccess: null
    readyState: "done"
    result: 3
    source: IDBObjectStore

transaction: IDBTransaction
__proto__: IDBRequest
```

Which is correct but I just want it to say 3 not loads of other stuff.

Comment: Just to clarify, you'd like to count the number of objects in your `objectstore` rather than the `database`? You can count the number of `objectstores` at the database-level but not objects themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit of introduction in order. From my [personal docs](http://dashdb.com/#/docs/general/transaction/requests) on transactions:

> Certain transactions return data, or "results", from the database.
>   These transactions are called "requests" and with the exception of
>   database opening, the values are always various combinations of object
>   "keys" and "values" and instances of IDBRequest. Request transactions
>   are just that: a transaction request," namely the act of asking for
>   something rather than the getting of it. A programmer encounters them
>   when dealing with IDBObjectStore, IDBIndex or IDBCursor objects.

What you're looking at is an `IDBRequest` object, which is returned by the `count()` method. That represents the request for data, and not the data itself.

The data itself is available after the `complete` event fires, and can be accessed via the `IDBRequest.result` property.

Here's a tested count method from [my library, dash](https://github.com/editor/dash/blob/c5fa325a720d22803714b32dd20f8afd47c8eb8c/lib/dash.dev.js#L673):

```
API.entries.count = function (count_ctx) {
  var request;
  if (API.exists(count_ctx.index)) {
    count_ctx.idx = count_ctx.objectstore.index(count_ctx.index);
    request = API.isEmpty(count_ctx.key) ? count_ctx.idx.count() : count_ctx.idx.count(count_ctx.key);
  } else {
    request = API.isEmpty(count_ctx.key) ? count_ctx.objectstore.count() : count_ctx.objectstore.count(count_ctx.key);
  }

  count_ctx.transaction.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
    count_ctx.error = event.target.error.message;
    API.error(count_ctx);
  });

  request.addEventListener('success', function () {
    count_ctx.total = request.result;
    API.success(count_ctx);
  });
```

I'll note that I probably should have used the `complete` event rather than the `success` event. I can't explain why but sometimes result values are not available in `success` callbacks.

Comment: Could you explain how implement this in my code? I really thankfull you taking time to explain your answer

Comment: Of course! I believe you want to attach a callback to the transaction you've created and listen for its completion. Then reach into `event.result` and you should find an integer representing the count of objects: https://gist.github.com/editor/21aeefd96e6b853c5671

Comment: When trying this i get count undefined, will try debugging it

Comment: I goofed up on the gist. Try checking `count.result` (it should be updated now). It's the `IDBRequest ` that has a value, not the event.

Comment: Boom, you god! Thanks. I've just had to recode a localstorage website and convert everything. IndexedDB seems really good just allot to learn  I guess but with the amount of storage i guess its going to be use alot more!

Comment: Here's to hoping. [Follow me on Twitter](http://twitter.com/taylorbuley) if you want more IDB news. Trying to help create a community around the folks using the technology

Comment: I'll make sure to keep my eyes open, will try keep active on this section. Followed :)

Comment: "sometimes result values are not available" may be related to this issue http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014JanMar/0575.html I prefer as current behaviour, i.e, you have to use transaction complete to get definite result. But performance gain is not ignorable.

Comment: Voted this down because it appears more like a promo for the respondent's own library than a genuine answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 14):

Bring back record count with a little less code:

```
var store = db.transaction(['trans']).objectStore('trans');
var count = store.count();
count.onsuccess = function() {
    console.log(count.result);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["data"], "readonly");
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("data"); 
var count = objectStore.count();

count.onsuccess = function() {
    console.log(count.result);
};
```

Comment: Is var cursor = objectStore.openCursor();   required? +1 for opening it readonly though.

Comment: For iterating through the objects only, cursor is required.. Here, it is not required..